# Enunciate not generating documentation

Tags: clojure, jax-rs, enunciate

I am trying to generate enunciate documentation form a mix of classes, all JAX-RS annotated, some coded inn java, some in clojure.

I have built a maven project that simply depends on a war file containing the service classes:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.enunciate</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enunciate-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.27</version>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>src/conf/enunciate.xml</configFile>
                <additionalClasspathEntries>
                    ${settings.localRepository}/com/ws/scholar/0.96-SNAPSHOT/scholar-0.96-SNAPSHOT.war
                </additionalClasspathEntries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>scholar</artifactId>
                    <version>0.96-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <type>war</type>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I cannot get any service documentation to generate.

When running mvn enunciate:docs -X, I see my classes "Noticed":

[DEBUG] Noticed class WEB-INF.classes.com.ws.scholar.resources.ClientResource in /.m2/repository/com/ws/scholar/0.96-SNAPSHOT/scholar-0.96-SNAPSHOT.war.

Can anyone offer guidance or corrections to my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't just add a war as a dependency and have the classes therein get picked up on the classpath. A war isn't a jar.

Instead, you'll probably need to use the [`attachClasses`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses) parameter of the `maven-war-plugin` to export your classes as a jar in addition to the war. Then you can depend on that jar like this:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>scholar</artifactId>
                <version>0.96-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <classifier>classes</classifier>
            </dependency>
```